# EF Core 3.1 Creating Views in Sqlite in-memory database for testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core 3.1 to build out my Database Models for SqlServer.  I'm also using EF generated migration files to handle database changes.  For testing, I'm spinning up in-memory Sqlite relational database as described in microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite.

All my tests were running as expected until I added Views to my database.  Views were added according to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types.

Based on Microsoft documentation, an example of a test should look something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Add_writes_to_database()
{
    // In-memory database only exists while the connection is open
    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        // Create the schema in the database
        using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        // Run the test against one instance of the context
        using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
            var service = new BlogService(context);
            service.Add("https://example.com");
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Use a separate instance of the context to verify correct data was saved to database
        using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
            Assert.Equal(1, context.Blogs.Count());
            Assert.Equal("https://example.com", context.Blogs.Single().Url);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The line `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` ensures that the database is created.  It creates the database, tables, and inserts associated data; according to specified logic in my `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

The problem is, **it does not create the View**.  According to documentation; This is the expected behaviour.

My code to create the View looks very much like the example code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<BlogPostsCount>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.ToView("View_BlogPostCounts");
            eb.Property(v => v.BlogName).HasColumnName("Name");
        });
}
```

I do have manually modified migration file that will create the View using raw sql.  And this works on SqlServer, but it appears the `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` method ignores the migration files on creating database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Really wish this one had an answer

Comment: We have the same issue with .NET5 and SQLite. Views are not created at all. Our work around for the time beeing is to manually create the Views with RAW SQL. That means first we create the database (`context.Database.EnsureCreated()`) and then we execute RAW SQL (`context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(<sql>)`). We don't have so many Views and we don't expect so many changes here but if possible we would like to avoid this work around because it causes effort in maintenance.

Comment: Got the same issue and didn't find any solution.
Thanks @ThomasPurrer your work around is really works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my very extensive research and testing, I have to say **no, this can't be done**. Save yourself time and frustration.

Views are not supported feature in EF Core + SQLite, event when you inject them by yourself via raw SQL script. I did very extensive troubleshooting but it simply doesn't work.

Jimmy Bogard, the [author](https://github.com/jbogard) of MediatR & AutoMapper wrote the problems with in-memory providers in [this](https://jimmybogard.com/avoid-in-memory-databases-for-tests/) article and I eventually have to agree with him. I basically discovered the same problems, just the hard way.

BTW: If you think "OK, I will switch to SQLite file then", this will not help much either. Many things get complicated (*number of DB providers in DI, support of third party library like Respawn (*also from Jimmy*), race conditions on DbFile*).

The robust solution here is Docker and DBs in containers. Invest your energy into this approach.